# pandas group by, aggregate using multiple agg functions on input columns

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am looking to do some aggregation on a pandas groupby dataframe, where I need to apply several different custom functions on multiple columns. This operation is very easy and customary in R (using `data.table` or `dplyr`), but I am surprised I'm finding it so difficult in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[2,4,6,8,10,12],'C':[1,1,1,2,2,2]})

#These work
data.groupby('C').apply(lambda x: x.A.mean() - x.B.mean())
data.groupby('C').agg(['mean','std'])

#but this doesn't
data.groupby('C').agg([lambda x: x.A.mean() - x.B.mean(),
                       lambda x: len(x.A)])
```

I want to calculate a statistic but also the sample size in each group, which seems like it should be a one or two line solution, but I also sometimes need to apply multiple functions on multiple columns of the grouped data frame.

Comment: Is this what you want? data.groupby('C').agg(['mean','std', 'size'])

Comment: It seems when you pass a list of functions, pandas goes column by column to apply each function to each column. When you pass a single function, it checks whether that's possible, if not it applies the function on the DataFrame instead. So it fails when you have a function involving more than one column in a list of functions. Not sure if it's a bug or design choice.

Comment: Get this done in separate steps: `f1 = lambda x: x.A.mean() - x.B.mean()`; `f2 = lambda x: len(x.A)`; `grouped = data.groupby('C')`; `pd.concat([grouped.apply(f1),grouped.apply(f2)],axis=1)`.

Comment: @Abdou that works but it seems like a lot of trouble for something that is a one liner in R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a one-liner, you can do this:

```
#use apply instead of agg to create multiple columns
data.groupby('C').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.A.mean() - x.B.mean(), len(x.A)])).rename(columns={0:'diff',1:'a_len'})
Out[2346]: 
   diff  a_len
C             
1  -2.0    3.0
2  -5.0    3.0
```

Another solution without using rename.

```
data.groupby('C').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([[x.A.mean() - x.B.mean(), len(x.A)]],columns=['diff','a_len']))
Out[24]: 
     diff  a_len
C               
1 0  -2.0      3
2 0  -5.0      3
```

Comment: There is no way to set the names without renaming the columns?

Comment: Was looking for this everywhere. Thanks a lot! It is strange that this is so easy to do in R, but so opaque in python

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of the extra 0's added to the index?

Answer (score 3):

We can write a function that does the custom functions on multiple columns and returns the result as a data frame.

```
>>> def meandiff_length(data):
            data['mean_diff'] = data.A.mean() - data.B.mean()
            data['a_length'] = len(data.A)
            return data
```

We can group the data and apply the custom function to the groups separately.

```
>>> data.groupby('C').apply(meandiff_length)
   A   B  C  mean_diff  a_length
0  1   2  1       -2.0         3
1  2   4  1       -2.0         3
2  3   6  1       -2.0         3
3  4   8  2       -5.0         3
4  5  10  2       -5.0         3
5  6  12  2       -5.0         3
```

This specific custom function returns the same value in every row, so it may be of your interest to use `drop_duplicates`. However, this is a general solution that will also work when our custom function becomes more complex.

Comment: Your function doesn't return the correct difference in each group. Group 1 should have a difference of 2 and group 2 should have a difference of 3.

Comment: @AllenWang careless mistake, sorry. I fixed with `return data` rather than `return data[['mean_diff', 'a_length']]`